# Need assistance implementing full text search

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fts4

I have a Note app which running for a while, now I am implementing full text search feature, I read a bout the sqlite fts3 & fts4 modules.

I want to know that after creating virtual table for full text search do I have to copy all data from my normal table to virtual table?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#populating_fts_tables) says:

> FTS tables are populated using INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements in the same way as ordinary SQLite tables are.

This is true even for [external content tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#the_content_option_).